# Autofac property injection in base class

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, autofac

I am working on a Windows Phone 8.1 application and I have a base class with public property.

```
public class ViewModelBase
{
   public ISomeClass MyProp {get;set;}
}
```

My derived class looks like this

```
public class MainViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    private readonly INavigation _navigation;
    public MainViewModel(INavigation navigation)
    {
        _navigation = navigation;
    }
}
```

In my App.cs I have

```
 var builder = new ContainerBuilder();
 builder.RegisterType<Navigation>().As<INavigation>();
 builder.RegisterType<SomeClass>().As<ISomeClass>();
 builder.RegisterSource(new AnyConcreteTypeNotAlreadyRegisteredSource());
```

When MainViewModel is created my INavigation is resolved but MyProp is null.
I have tried

```
builder.Register(c => new ViewModelBase { MyProp = c.Resolve<ISomeClass>() });

builder.Register(c => new ViewModelBase()).OnActivated(e => e.Instance.MyProp = e.Context.Resolve<ISomeClass>());

builder.RegisterType<ViewModelBase>().PropertiesAutowired();
```

but none of it works!

Solution posted here 
http://bling.github.io/blog/2009/09/07/member-injection-module-for-autofac/

works but I don't like it :)

I don't want to use constructor injection in this case.

Thank you.

Comment: Can you explain why you "don't want to use constructor injection" when it would clearly solve the problem with barely any effort.

Comment: Because I would have to add a dependency in a derived class constructor and pass it to the base constructor.

Comment: And you don't like that because? `public MainViewModel(INavigation navigation, ISomeClass someClass) : base (someClass)`  This is much easier for people coming after you to understand, they can see everything your class depends on.

Comment: I understand what you are saying and agree with you. I would like to minimize the amount of typing. Maybe it won't be so easy to see on what my class depends on but for now I can live with that. The real question is why doesn't autofac property injection work?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You must make sure that your viewmodel class, `MainViewModel`, is registered with property injection. Currently, all you have registered with property injection is `ViewModelBase`, but think about what you are *resolving*. You will never resolve `ViewModelBase`, you're resolving `MainViewModel`s. So that is what needs to be registered in the container.

Try:

```
builder.RegisterType<MainViewModel>().PropertiesAutowired();
```

Answer (score 18):

This will load up all classes that inherit `ViewModelBase` and inject only the specific properties that you want. A lot of the time, you don't want the other properties on the child class to be injected.

```
builder.RegisterAssemblyTypes( GetType().Assembly )
    .AssignableTo<ViewModelBase>()
    .OnActivated( args =>
    {
        var viewModel = args.Instance as ViewModelBase;
        if( viewModel != null )
        {
            viewModel.MyProp = args.Context.Resolve<ISomeClass>();
        }
    } );
```

Comment: This is a great answer if you want to keep property injection limited and not open it to all child classes (when the reason is merely to avoid changing many constructors for example).

Comment: @Meligy Yes, however a simpler way to do this with Controllers is builder.RegisterControllers(typeof(MvcApplication).Assembly).AssignableTo<BaseController>().PropertiesAutowired();

Answer (score 0):

If you can't add more parameters in the constructor of derived class, try use the `required` property: https://autofac.readthedocs.io/en/latest/register/prop-method-injection.html#required-properties